# Student Count App InputBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a VB App, that basically is just a text box and a button, you type a number into the textbox to show how many students are in the class and then when you press the button it displays input boxes to enter the students name.

So far I have this:

```
if txtStudentNumber.Text = "1" Then
InputBox.Show "Enter Student Name"
End If
```

(Yes I know the InputBox code is wrong, I just forgot what I wrote lol)

But it doesn't work, I want it to work so that if I was to type 13, it would prompt me to enter name after name until it has reached 13. But I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated

tl;dr:

- Enter number of students
- Display separate InputBoxes until it reaches the number of students

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it server side after clicking the button, put this on your button click handler:

```
Dim Max = CInt(txtStudentNumber.Text) - 1
For value as Integer = 0 To Max
    Dim tb As New TextBox()
    Page.Controls.Add(tb)
Next
```

This adds the textboxes in your page, if you already have a container where to put them you just need to change `Page.Controls.Add(tb)` to `MyContainer.Controls.Add(tb)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim student1 as string
    if txtStudentNumber.Text = "1" Then 
student1 = InputBox.Show("Enter Student Name")
    End If
```

Try this